# Python equivalent of perl's dbi/DBD::Proxy access? (Perl DBI/DBD::Proxy for Python)

Tags: python, perl, odbc, dbi

I have a Perl script that interfaces with an existing database (type of database is unknown) through the DBI module, that I would like to access in python 2.6 on WinXP.

The Perl code is:

```
use DBI;
my $DSN = "DBI:Proxy:hostname=some.dot.com;port=12345;dsn=DBI:XXXX:ZZZZZ";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($DSN);
```

Can this be translated into a python equivalent?

Following an example at ([Is there any pywin32 odbc connector documentation available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768250/is-there-any-pywin32-odbc-connector-documentation-available/768352#768352) ), I've put together the following:

```
import odbc
DSN = "DBI:Proxy:hostname=some.dot.com;port=12345;dsn=DBI:XXXX:ZZZZZ"
db = odbc.odbc(DSN)
```

But I get the error:

```
dbi.operation-error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified in LOGIN
```

**UPDATE**

It appears that another Perl module, DBD::Proxy is providing the actual interface to a Perl DBI::ProxyServer (server-side) implementation that handles the actual queries.

Can python be used to interface with the Perl-based [DBI::ProxyServer](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI::ProxyServer)?

http://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Proxy

http://hell.org.ua/Docs/oreilly/weblinux/dbi/ch08_02.htm

Comment: Is the same Perl code running on the same Windows machine without errors?

Comment: Good question.  I'm working on getting DBI installed, which is another problem.

Comment: Both ActiveState and Strawberry Perl Windows distributions have DBI bundled with them.

Comment: Seems I'm missing the DBD::Proxy module, I'm working on getting that installed.

Comment: I got the perl version of the script working now, no issues.

Answer (score 5):

Your python script doesn't have to be a line by line translation of your Perl script.

Why not just use the Python [DB-API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) compatible module for the database you want to access?  For MySQL, use [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html).  For PostgreSQL, use [PyGreSQL](http://www.pygresql.org/).

Or search Google for "YourDatabaseName + python"

Comment: -1: "doesn't have to be a line-by-line translation" should be "can't be a line-by-line translation".

Comment: What if I don't know the backend database? (I suppose I could try different modules).  Does the Perl DBI module magically figure out the backend db from the given $DSN value?

Comment: A database can never be consulted entirely generically... ports, connection protocols, sql syntax... all slightly different. The Python DB-API provides a common interface that each database's driver should implement so that the basics are as consistent as possible. Perl's DBI is the same... a layer of indirection designed to isolate each DB's (and DB-driver's) libraries.

Comment: Yes, perl DBI automagically loads DBD::xx when asked to connect to a URL starting "dbi:xx:", so in this case DBD::Proxy.

I guess the underlying problem is that DBD::Proxy isn't a real database driver, but a connector to talk to a bridge on some.dot.com whose dsn is (hopefully) a real database driver. Which is likely to use a DBD::Proxy-specific protocol.

Comment: araqnid, ok this is making more sense now.  That sounds like what it's doing from what I can see.  And would explain my DBD::Proxy error I'm getting in the perl version at the moment.  Now is there a way to duplicate the DBD::Proxy functionality in python?

Comment: It should be possible, but a quick glance at DBD/Proxy.pm suggests it will be a *lot* of work. For instance, you'll need to figure out how the protocol for RPC::PlClient works. That itself uses Storable to marshal Perl objects, and that's a nontrivial transformation to Python: depends on how complicated the DBI-related objects are.

Comment: Yeah, it's looking difficult, I'll probably just end up using the perl.

Answer (score 0):

[sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) is pretty nice.

Comment: Can sqlalchemy interface with a Perl DBI::ProxyServer?

Comment: Why on earth would you want a Python DB framework to integrate with a perl DBI construct, especially given that there are perfectly functional database interfaces in Python?

Comment: or perhaps i just answered before that last line was added to the update.